# C# MongoDB Driver Aggregate() always throw cast exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to join collections with Lookup function:

```
var docs = await Items
    .Aggregate()
    .Lookup("categories", "categoryId", "_id", "category")
    .ToListAsync();
```

but i always get:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonString' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'.
```

and the single object in the returned result has a lot of properties that bears exception:

[image: img]

even if i use only Aggregate():

```
var docs = await Items
    .Aggregate()
    .ToListAsync();
```

It still returns the same result.

Comment: Can you provide sample data for both collection for reproduce purpose? Thanks.

Comment: It really doesn't matter, but let's say that I have Item has Id, Title and CategoryId
and Category that has Id and Name

Comment: `and the single object in the returned result has a lot of properties that bears exception:` - this expected since thrown exception just say that you can't convert a document into `bool`/`int` and etc. You should provide your data. I vote that error is not about aggregation, but about mapping your data

Comment: These properties belong to the BsonDocument object.
indeed I didn't have many of these types in my models, so there is no mapping to do!